# Debugging multiprocess project with GDB

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I'd like to to debug a multiprocess C++ project with GDB, specifically I'd like to know if there is a way to achieve the following

- Attach multiple processes to a single instance of GDB while letting all the processes run
- Setting up a breakpoint in the source code of one of the processes stops all the attached processes

The ideal solution would be something similar to what is offered by the Visual Studio debugger as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-multiple-processes?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Switch_processes__break_and_continue_execution__step_through_source).
At the moment I'm able to attach multiple processes to a GDB instance but then only the current selected inferior is executed while the others are stopped and waiting for a continue command.

Comment: You can set asynchronous mode `set target-async on` and tell each inferior in turn to `continue&` (with an ampersand). This sends them to the background.  As for stopping, you will need to create a gdb script that interrupts all inferiors, and assign it to your breakpoint(s).

Comment: Thank you very much, `set target-async on` was exactly what I needed. If you post the comment as an answer I will accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to run inferiors in the background, one needs to issue this `gdb` command

```
set target-async on
```

after start up and before running anything. With this option in effect, one ca issue

```
continue&
```

(or just `c&`) and this will send the inferior to the background, giving an opportunity to switch to run another one.

Stopping all inferiors at once is a bit more difficult. There is no built-in command for that. Fortunately `gdb` is scriptable and it is possible to attach a script to a breakpoint. Once the breakpoint is hit, the commands are executed. Put `inferior n` and `interrupt` commands in the script for each inferior. It is probably more convenient to do that from a Python script, something like

```
(gdb) python
>inf = gdb.inferiors()
>for i in inf:
>  gdb.execute("inferior %d" % i.num)
>  gdb.execute("interrupt")
```